# resolveLocalFileSystemURL is not a function - angular2

Tags: cordova, angular, cordova-plugin-file

I am learning `angular2` with typescript for developing mobile app. Trying to write logs and store them in device location.

I am using cordova file plugin to achieve this but when I try to get the directory with *window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL*, browser throws error "window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL" is not a function.

Comment: this is more related to cordova not angular 2 check your 'file' plugin in cordova

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file?

Comment: got any solution?

Comment: the problem is with related to the file plugin which I added. It worked when I removed and added the plugin again.

Answer (score 2):

In that case, use it like following -

```
window['resolveLocalFileSystemURL']
```

Your code would then look like this -

```
window['resolveLocalFileSystemURL'](folderpath, function(dir) {
    // Your code goes here
});
```